# how to find indices based on equality of some cols with a set (Query on matrix) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with n rows and 3 columns. lets call it `A=[23 45 6;32 4 78;67 5 34; 54 1 4;6 9 2]`

Now I have a set of points: `B={  P1=[X1,Y1] P2=[X2,Y2] ... }= { [6 9] [32 4] }`

I want to set a query on matrix `A` so that it returns me the index of the rows(i) in which for all set `B`:

```
Pk(1,1) ( or Xk) == A(i,1) && Pk(1,2) ( or Yk) == A(i,2)
```

In other words,set the query based on column 1 && 2 over `A` and compared them with `B`, so the output is the index of rows that has same values in col 1 and 2 with the Xk,Yk in `B`:

output: 5,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place B in a matrix format as well, for example:

```
B=[6 9; 32 4];
```

Here is a MATLAB code that you can use to do this:

```
 k=0;
 output=[];
 for n=1:5
   for m=1:2 
     if (sum(A(n,1:2)==B(m,:)) == 2)
       k = k +1;
       output(k) = n;
     end
    end
  end
```

your result is in `output`.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm adding an explanation of the line `(sum(A(n,1:2)==B(m,:)) == 2)`. Lets look at it piece by piece. `A(n, 1:2)` gives us a 1x2 vector which is the first two columns of the nth row of `A`. `B(m,:)` is also a 1x2 vector as B only has two columns. So let's say that we now have `[6 9]` from the last row of `A` and `[6 9]` from the first row of `B`.

Try `[6 9] == [6 9]` in the command line. The result is a logical vector: `[1 1]`. The reason is that `==` will compare the vectors element by element. So the first 1 is because 6 equals 6 and the second tells us the 9s are equal. If you try `[6 9] == [7 9]` you'll get `[0 1]` because the first elements are now different.

Thus to assess if BOTH elements are the same we expect the sum of the vector that results from the `==` operator to equal two. If it equals 1 then only one element was the same, we need it to be 2 to say the whole vector is equal (2 because the vectors only have 2 elements). So `sum([6 9] == [6 9])` gives `2` but `sum([7 9] == [6 9])` only gives `1`.

Hence the condition to test for the equality of a row is `if (sum(A(n,1:2)==B(m,:)) == 2)`

Comment: What is this line for " if (sum(A(n,1:2)==B(m,:)) = 2) "?  

and shouldnt it be == instead of =2 ?

Comment: The line shows that elements of first and second column of row n of A both are equal to column 1 and 2 of row m of B.

Comment: sum could be a bit wobbly as it might find two elements that the sum of them equals to B(m,:) but the numbers are not same 
A(1,1:2) = [12 8 ]
B(2,:)= [ 9 11 ]

Comment: Farzin: this line compares the first element of Row n of A against first element of Row m of B, if they are the same it returns 1. It also compares the second element of row n of A agains the second elemt of row m of B, if they are the same it returns 1 as well, so if both elements are equal there are two ones retuned which their sum will be 2. For example if you type: A(5,1:2) == B(1,:) it will return `ans = 1 1`.

Comment: TJ1:
It compares the sum of elements in col 1,2 in row 1.
Have you tried the code?

Comment: @farzinparsa A(n,1:2)==B(m,:) is an element-wise comparison and return a logical vector. This code does work. Have YOU tried it? You should debug and step through it and execute that line in the command line piece by piece to get a better understanding. My code also works. Have neither of these answers solved your problem?

Comment: @Dan:
So whats the sum doing there? [ although the syntax up there is wrong )

Comment: @farzinparsa the sum is there to make sure both elements are equal. If both are equal it returns a vector of two ones which their sum becomes two.

Comment: Farzinparsa by the way the syntax now is correct thanks to @Dan for correcting it and thanks to you for finding the mistake.

Comment: TJ1:
it's alright, but I still got problem with the Sum, could you explain abit more please.

Comment: @farzinparsa I have added a detailed explanation to this answer because understanding that line is fairly elementary matlab and you wont get far without it. But I must stress that the solution I posted is much simpler and probably more efficient and is the correct way to do what you want. It's good to try and understand this answer, but correct matlab would be to use intersect.

Comment: @Dan:
what a smart way, thanks alot for explanation; at least I learned something new today,

Answer (score 2):

Make B a matrix as suggested by @TJ1

```
B=[6 9; 32 4];
```

Just use [intersect with the rows options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#btcnv0p-12) (and the second output)

```
[~, i, ~] = intersect(A(:, 1:2), B, 'rows')
```

I have indexed on the first 2 columns from `A` because you are only interested in those columns and obviously intersect wants the two matrices to have the same number of columns.

The result:

```
i =

     5
     2
```